# React Typescript generic: when Component props is function and use argument, Typescript type is unknown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

React version 15 or 18.
Typescript version 4.9.5.

When only write  argument of getData, and not use, checkable generic is error;

First MyComponent is correctly, argument of getData is empty;

Second MyComponent is incorrect, argument of getData is non-empty;

```
interface IProps<T = any> {
  getData: (params: any) => Promise<{ dataSource: T[] }>;

  checkable: (data: T) => string;
}

function MyComponent<T>(props: IProps<T>) {
  return <div></div>;
}

class MyPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyComponent
          getData={() => {
            // 1. When can't use params

            return Promise.resolve({ dataSource: [{ name: 'Jay' }] });
          }}
          checkable={(item) => {
            return item.name; // *** correctly ***
          }}
        />
        <MyComponent
          getData={(params) => {
            // 2. When use params

            return Promise.resolve({ dataSource: [{ name: 'Jay' }] });
          }}
          checkable={(item) => {
            return item.name; // *** incorrect ***
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example using `params`, you haven't given a type for `params`. Oddly, TypeScript infers it correctly (from the type of `getData`), but then apparently fails to correctly infer `T`. If you add the type, it works:

```typescript
class MyPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent
                    getData={() => {
                        // 1. When can't use params

                        return Promise.resolve({
                            dataSource: [{ name: "Jay" }],
                        });
                    }}
                    checkable={(item) => {
                        return item.name;
                    }}
                />
                <MyComponent
                    getData={(params: any) => {
                        //          ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− CHANGE IS HERE
                        // 2. When use params

                        return Promise.resolve({
                            dataSource: [{ name: "Jay" }],
                        });
                    }}
                    checkable={(item) => {
                        return item.name;
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgEkAFHMAZwB4AVOAF44KagE8AfHADe5OPLgBzJDAAiKGCgBccABRgUUFCC47RYgJRCpHXMC5Ie0uABMNKAMoQArlDRIdPgBtAF04AF8JCjkFNAALJDQAaxQAIwAbAL03TUCrQSkuGCgaRQpwykxvagxgCGo4AFkxAGFcSGokWn4JfU5TVltuHqtZBTgiGF8GnhdgADcJHgB6OcXyyjR0lC4uJrE2FGU4JAAPOmoXPeR0GAA6NvB6rvgxhSJL+l1RmPH5Semel+f3GswWEmBIJBPGajw6L0hUKRyjU7kE0m+1hkiKRuLgy2WcAAjHc4AB1BINNCiADk8G8DjgBiMJkoePZ7xUgNsIHsSDuRC4EHS8yQujeHMlrncXl8-h0QWc1GMWXwACkUGJ8BEQgAaHFShThCwUQ1-cIVM3jeKJFIZJDo3TAOggfJSCVW8YAqANZ1IEB3ZUgJCmz0RS2G5YQs0w1rtZ60A0clHqTSO5nGAbmN3YsN-Al4gB6xeLgCQicsVytV6uVuAtAASAEEAHIAcQAoqwPHB6+2EO2k5HCQAmUkUrpwBnMDOswdS70NHl8gVIIUisUevPjHKeHx+LKKuBB1UarU6-Vbo0mue4i03pE25JpTKOv2urGbsMLuBvwMq0OeneZpRjeKxrNGULXuMFThEAA)

I wish I could tell you **why** you need the type, but sadly I don't know. I'd think the `params` type was clear from the signature of `getData` in `IProps<T>`, where it's explicitly `any`. But adding a type (any type) fixes the error.

Comment: That's true, but I'm just as confused as you are. It's only right that TS should infer automatically